# why does it skip and continue even if the first if statement is true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested-loops

As you can immidiately see this is a for loop with some if conditionals right here( is that what you say "if conditionals" ???).
I HAVE 2 QUESTIONS ACTUALLY.

I am working on CodeAcademy, and it has asked me to do this:

```
Print out the numbers from 1 - 20.
The rules:
For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the console.
Otherwise, just print out the number.**
```

This is what I have done so far and I do think it's working correct and is in general correct and everything, but CodeAcademy doesn't say it is. I would like to hear if someone knows if there is something wrong with my code, or if this is only a different way to do the exact thing they are requesting(referring to the rules above).

Also the second question, this is more the curious question of mine. If we take 15 as an example for now. How does JavaScript think when it encounters 15. 
If 15 is dividable by 3 and has 0 left, shouldn't it console.log("Fizz"), instead of going all the way down to the almost last bottom code and console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
Can someone explain this to me, pleeaassee :)

```
 for (var iterator = 1; iterator <= 20; iterator = iterator + 1) {
        if (iterator % 3 === 0) {
            console.log("Fizz");

        } else if (iterator % 5 === 0) {
            console.log("Buzz");

        } else if (iterator % 3 === 0) {
            if (iterator % 5 === 0) {
                console.log("FizzBuzz");
            }
        } else {
            console.log(iterator);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you not debug with firebug?

Comment: You're right, 15 should not produce "FizzBuzz" with this code. Are you saying that it does?

Comment: 15 meets your first condition as it's divisible by 3 so the test for divisible by 5 and 3 never executes. Test for by 3 and by 5 first is the quick way.

Comment: @Michael Myers Yes it does, it does. Do you want me to include the results?

Comment: Edited the question, the results are there.

Comment: I am sorry people, I think I have done a couple of personal mistakes which has caused me to express myself not quite correctly :P

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and do not get the output you described, with 15 successfully printing "FizzBuzz". I get the expected result of 15 being displayed as "Fizz". It's not working correctly, for the reason that it doesn't have a chance to reach the final if statement to print out "FizzBuzz" for 15. A simple fix would be to check for divisibility by 5 when the number is divisible by 3.

```
for (var iterator = 1; iterator <= 20; iterator = iterator + 1) {
    if (iterator % 3 === 0) {
        if (iterator % 5 === 0) {
            console.log("FizzBuzz"); //divisible by 3 and 5
        } else {
            console.log("Fizz"); //only divisible by 3
        }
    } else if (iterator % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz"); //only divisible by 5
    } else {
        console.log(iterator); //not divisible by 3 or 5
    }
}
```

Comment: I have realized that I have told wrong info here, but now one thing worries me. How does JavaScript know weather to console.log Fizz, Buzz or FizzBuzz when something is dividable by 3, 5 and 3 and 5, besides thinking of the sequence of the if statements. Can JavaScript go through all the code and then execute?

Comment: @user2097217: the JavaScript interpreter goes through all the code step-by-step. I suggest you set a breakpoint at the first `if` condition and then step through your code for each instance of `iterator` and see how it behaves.

Comment: JavaScript Rocks!!!!! :D :D :D

Answer (score -1):

It might give you the solution:
Just rearrange the code:

```
for (var iterator = 1; iterator <= 20; iterator = iterator + 1) {

   if (iterator % 3 === 0) {
       if (iterator % 5 === 0) {
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
        }
    }else if (iterator % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");

    } else if (iterator % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");

    } else {
        console.log(iterator);
    }

}
```

First check the condition for that satisfy both divisible by 3 and 5.
After that check for 3 and 5 separately.

Comment: No, now the second condition is never reached.

Comment: This is kind of paradoxical to me cause 15 is divideble by 3 and by 5, how does it know weather to console.log Fizz or FizzBuzz or Buzz??